# text elaboration with neural network non natural language

Tags: neural-network, text

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to elaborate with the neural network 2 input strings and predict a result string. I'm doing this job manually and it's really time consuming: basically i have something like this

input 1 : "MEAS-CABC2S-AIR04-CO-AVG" (like a tag name of the signal) input 2 : "Scaled average value" (description of the signal)

the corresponding output should be the object associated to this signal output: CO-AIR-04 (sometimes is a substring of the tagname sometime is a substring of the description)

Mentally the steps i'm doing to understand what's the corresponding object is by mentally splitting (by "-") the input 1 and with the description understand what is the corresponding object.

My idea is to feed into the neural network the all substrings ['MEAS', 'CABC2S', 'AIR04', 'CO', 'AVG', 'Scaled', 'average', 'value'] and for the expected output ["CO", "AIR", "04"] or directly the entire string like so CO-AIR-04

Am i completely wrong about this idea?

Comment: "....sometimes is a substring of the tagname sometime is a substring of the description....". Hoe do you decide this ?

Comment: it's something that is totally random. Sometimes the input1 in completely useless and you have to use only the input2.